# What's the best way to get an object from multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

Say I have the following 2 tables:

TABLE 1: users
user_id INT
first_name VARCHAR

TABLE 2: items
user_id INT
item_title VARCHAR

What is the best method to SELECT the data so I end up with data looking like:

```
$user[0]['user_id']=1;
$user[0]['first_name']='Dave';
$user[0]['items'][0]['item_title']='car';
$user[0]['items'][1]['item_title']='house';
$user[0]['items'][2]['item_title']='horse';
$user[1]['user_id']=2;
$user[1]['first_name']='Steve';
$user[1]['items'][0]['item_title']='bike';
$user[1]['items'][1]['item_title']='kite';
```

I know how to get the data with multiple queries in a loop, but that is bad practice.
I also know that I can get all the rows with a JOIN and then loop through the data to model it like above.. But what is the best approach?

As a side note question... Is this what you would use an ORM for?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are looking for a `PHP` based solution but you can use `GROUP_CONCAT()` along with `JOIN` like below .

```
select u.user_id,u.first_name, xx.itemlist
from users u join (
select user_id, 
group_concat(item_title) as itemlist
from items
group by user_id) xx on u.user_id = xx.user_id;
```